# Changes required in my Transition diagram

Tags: regex, dfa, nfa

My transition table:

[image: My transition table]

Here in the image what are the difference between **r* and s*** for **r and s**

What changes should be in my TD?

My TD:

[image: My TD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your notation, but I believe the '*' marks the state as final or accepting. So, what you need to change in your diagram is to mark the `r` state as final, drawing a double circle, the same way you drew the `s` state.